# TcpClient - how to determine when bytes are delivered?

Tags: .net, tcp, .net-4.0, tcpclient

When using TcpClient, how do I know what the server has or has not received?  For example, let's say my message is a very long string:

```
string myAppMessage = "was up too late coding, bla, bla, bla, ....."
byte[] allBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( myAppMessage );
```

And I want to hand-off the string, in entirety, to TCP and I want to know that that entire string was delivered to and received by the server.

There seem to be some common ways to send data via TCP:

```
var client = new TcpClient( IP_ADDR , PORT )
client.GetStream().Write( allBytes )
```

-or-

`client.Client.Send( allBytes )`

Does either or both guarantee the delivery of the entire message?  In the first case, is it only guaranteed after I call `Flush()` on the stream?  I think one or both of the above are blocking calls.  If completed without an Exception being thrown, can I take that to mean that the entire message was delivered/received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to receive acknowledgement from the other side. Alternatives:

1. Have the remote party send you an acknowledgement.
2. Have the remote party `Shutdown(Read)` the connection. Call `Read` until it returns 0. 0 signals that the remote side has shut down and all data was received.
3. Call Shutdown(Write). This waits for an acknowledgement from the remote side.

Sending alone does not guarantee delivery.

Comment: Hi usr - I'm not sure how to implement these suggestions.  Do you have any code samples that you could share?  Note that I have no influence on the remote side, other than using standard TCP.

Comment: See (3). This is the only way you can make sure that data was received without cooperation from the remote side. Actually, your machine could wait for an acknowledgement from the remote side without shutting down but this feature is not exposed by any API that I know of.

Comment: usr - could you say a little more about #3?  Isn't TCP receiving ACKs as it streams the bytes to the remote party?  Seems extreme to have to end the connection to get confirmation that everything previously sent was received?

Comment: Yes. The acks come in over time. Listening for one of them would be enough, but this feature is not exposed by the OS through any API. It could be but it is not AFAIK. Is the remote side sending you any data that you could use to infer that your data was received?

Comment: HI Usr - Unfortunately not.  This is a one-way stream.  Thanks for your help on this one!